# Using pageviewer with custom layout in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

i am new to android and while gallery is being showing as depreciated try to use the viewpager concept to dynamically loading custom layout which consist of imageview and textview everything is going great but while loading the viewpager the image appear to left and right side of the viewpager and showing large space so the question is how can we remove the space in between the page or view while using viewpager.
here is the screenshot what i try to achieve:
[image]

and here is what i am getting :

[image]

so as u see the red circled two image are those image which is adding to the viewpager and there is lot of space in between two image.

mentioning the pageadapter class where the image and text are there

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Integer> filter_image_arr;
    private ArrayList<String> filter_desc;
    private Context mcontext;
    private LayoutInflater inflator;
    private View layout;
    private TextView filter_title;
    private ImageView filter_image;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        mcontext=context;
        /*
         * add image to the arraylist
         */
        filter_image_arr=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        filter_image_arr.add(R.drawable.cakenormal);
        filter_image_arr.add(R.drawable.blur);
        filter_image_arr.add(R.drawable.emboss);
        filter_image_arr.add(R.drawable.gray);
        filter_image_arr.add(R.drawable.hue);
        filter_image_arr.add(R.drawable.monochrome);
        filter_image_arr.add(R.drawable.nored);
        filter_image_arr.add(R.drawable.oil);
        filter_image_arr.add(R.drawable.pixellate);
        filter_image_arr.add(R.drawable.posterize);
        filter_image_arr.add(R.drawable.sepia);
        filter_image_arr.add(R.drawable.vibrance);
        filter_image_arr.add(R.drawable.vintage);

        /*
         * add the desc for the filter effect....
         *
         */
        filter_desc=new ArrayList<String>();
        filter_desc.add("NORMAL");
        filter_desc.add("BLUR");
        filter_desc.add("EMBOSS");
        filter_desc.add("GRAY");
        filter_desc.add("HUE");
        filter_desc.add("MONOCHROME");
        filter_desc.add("NO RED");
        filter_desc.add("OIL");
        filter_desc.add("PIXELATE");
        filter_desc.add("POSTERIZE");
        filter_desc.add("SEPIA");
        filter_desc.add("VIBRANCE");
        filter_desc.add("VINTAGE");

        inflator=(LayoutInflater) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        layout=inflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_gallery_item_layout, null);

        filter_image=(ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.filter_image);
        filter_image.setImageResource(filter_image_arr.get(position));
        filter_image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);
        int padding=mcontext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin);
        filter_image.setTag(position);
        //filter_image.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        filter_title=(TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.filter_desc);
        filter_title.setText(filter_desc.get(position));
        filter_title.setTag(position);

        ((ViewPager)container).addView(layout, 0);


        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0==((View)arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return filter_image_arr.size();
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ((ViewPager)container).removeView((View)object);
    }


}
```

and here is the activity class where adding adapter to the viewpager

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    //private GPUImageView gpuimageview;
    private Button save_image;
    private Context mcontext;
    private ViewPager gallery_pager;
    private ImagePagerAdapter pageadapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mcontext=MainActivity.this;

        //gpuimageview=(GPUImageView) findViewById(R.id.gpuimageview);


        gallery_pager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        gallery_pager.setPageMargin(-50);
        gallery_pager.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
        gallery_pager.setFadingEdgeLength(30);

        pageadapter=new ImagePagerAdapter(mcontext);

        gallery_pager.setAdapter(pageadapter);

        gallery_pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }


}
```

so can anyone tell me how the thing can be achieve of the first screenshot or i go with the old gallery concept.

here the xml part which contain the viewpager

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/filtergallery_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:background="#AA000000" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/gpuimageview"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="save" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the custom layout which contain the imageview and textview which i m inflating

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/filter_image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filter_desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/filter_image"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:background="#07000000"
        android:text="filter" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

so any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: please post the xml file where you have defined the `ViewPager`

Comment: yah posted the xml part

Answer (score 0):

`WiewPager` doesn't support `wrap_content`, you can either set `match_parent`, or a fixed size . If you set `wrap_content` then it will be considered by the system as `match_parent`